# Designing a clipper circuit

Tags: diodes, diode-clamp

Design a clipper circuit using 1N4148 general purpose diodes and a R = 1 kΩ to clip input signal voltages that are above 5.7 V or less than −0.7 V. Below is my schematic in which Vo<=Vdo + 5V and Vo> =-Vdo. Vdo=0.7V. My question is if this circuit follows the specs.

[image: My clamp circuit schematic]

Comment: What happens when you simulate the circuit?

Comment: @DwayneReid I have not simulated yet.

Comment: Why not give that a try before asking us to do it for you?

Comment: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simulation of my schematic, it seems I built the correct clamp circuit.
[image: schematic]